# Select git branch depending of artifactory file

Tags: git, jenkins, artifactory

I have a jenkins job to execute my tests each time we have an official release. This job requires a specific branch depending of the new release version.

For instance, if the new release is 3.14.15.9.627, the branch has to be */ver/3.14.15.

Each time there is a new release, I have to change manually the job configuration to fit our needs in the next way:

- Changing Source Code Management>Branches to build to */ver/3.14.15
- Changing the Artifactory Configuration>Download Details>Spec to:

  ```
  "files": [  
  {
      "pattern": "my_repo/ver/3.14.15/3.14.15.9.627/*.exe",
      "target": "${WORKSPACE}/installer/"
  },
  ```

How can I configure both the git branch and the artifactory specs in function of the installers uploaded?

Comment: Hi, I offered a solution but if you can provide some specific details I can modify my solution to achieve your intended outcome. How do you build and publish your artifacts to Artifactory ? Do you use a tool like maven etc ? In your jenkins job you check out the repo, build, upload the artifact and then download it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your jenkins job automatically when there is a new release using webhooks. Your jenkins job can be configured as below for example and you can plugin the branch and repository name dynamically which can be retrieved from the webhook.

`checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "refs/heads/${branchName}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "git@bitbucket.org:${repoName}.git"]]]`

Configure your Artifactory download spec to something like below. If your artifact names are unique and can be retrieved from your build or repository then you can plug the value into a variable `artifact_name` and use it in your pattern.

```
"files": [  
{
    "pattern": "my_repo/ver/(*)/(*)/${artifact_name}*.exe",
    "target": "${WORKSPACE}/installer/"
}
```

OR

Configure your Artifactory download spec to something like below if your artifact names are not unique. For ex. if your new release is 3.14.15.9.627 and you can read this from a file or somewhere in your repo  ,you could grep and assign 3.14.15 to a variable `branchVersion` and 3.14.15.9.627 to a variable `releaseVersion`

```
"files": [  
{
    "pattern": "my_repo/ver/${branchVersion}/${releaseVersion}/*.exe",
    "target": "${WORKSPACE}/installer/"
}
```

If you are using a build tool like maven it becomes even easier